80s-2000s movie with magical furry Alien/Monster and a boy?
There is a movie I am looking for  but my dilemma is that I can't remember pretty much any of the plot. It's an old movie as well prob 80s maybe 90s doubt 2000s but could be a possibility... It had a fast little furry monster thing but the only thing I can remember about the plot was a scene where the kid was told by his mother to clean his room and the little monster cleaned it instantaneously. After that scene my memory completely goes blank but I can't remember find this movie to save my life..

Welcome to the community. Any other plot details? If you know, please also describe the language, country and year of production, plot locale, descriptions of actors, color or BW, etc. I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.
